# Saving inputs on the program to the Database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm developing a hotel management system for my project lecture at the university. I ask for you to help me fix the code that i've pasted below. I don't understand why it's not transferring and saving the inputs that i enter on the program in Visual Studio Express. This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    class Database
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        public Database()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("server=.,database=Guest; Integrated Security = True");
        }

        public bool AddGuest(string ID, string Phone, string Adress, string FName, string LName, string Email, string RoomNo)
        {
            bool durum = false;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"declare @guest_id nvarchar(50),@guest_phone nvarchar(50),@guest_adress ntext,@guest_fname ntext,@guest_lname ntext,@guest_email ntext,@room_no int = @room_no;
select @guest_id = Guest.guest_id from Guest where Guest.room_no = '103';
select @guest_phone = Guest.guest_phone from Guest where Guest.room_no = '103';
select @guest_adress = Guest.guest_adress from Guest where Guest.room_no = '103';
select @guest_fname = Guest.guest_fname from Guest where Guest.room_no = '103';
select @guest_lname = Guest.guest_lname from Guest where Guest.room_no = '103';
select @guest_email = Guest.guest_email from Guest where Guest.room_no = '103';

insert into Guest(guest_id,guest_phone,guest_adress,guest_fname,guest_lname,guest_email,room_no)values(@guest_id,@guest_adress,@guest_fname,@guest_lname,@guest_email,@room_no)

)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", Phone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adress", Adress);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", FName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", LName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@room_no", RoomNo);
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                durum = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            con.Close();
            return durum;
        }
        private void ekle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

For example, as you see in the picture, i'm entering the guest id, first name, last name, then i want them to be saved in the database. I connected the database with the visual, and created the code according to it. But still doesn't work.

Comment: You connection string should be either server=.\SQLExpress or .\SQLStandard.  I would use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server to help debug issues.  You can query the database to verify if data was added.  The name of the server in your connection string should be the same as the login window of SSMS.  You may be writing to wrong database so check all databases in SSMS explorer.

Comment: there is only one database, and I also am using SQL Server Management Studio 2014. This is the screenshot of my database login screen : http://i.hizliresim.com/MoayGg.png
And this one is the inside screenshot : http://i.hizliresim.com/DByRbv.png

Comment: Your connection string should be either server=,\cembilal or server=CEM-BILAL\cembilal.  'cembilal' is the instance of the database.  Your database name is also wrong is should be hocu (not Guest).   I normally in my SQL statement put 'Use hocu' at beginning of query to choose correct database. Or add the database name to the connection string.  You are not specifying hocu which lead me to believe you are writing to another instance of SQL Server.  The instance of SQL Server in your case is cembilal.  I suspect you have two instances of the SQL Server installed on your PC.

Comment: Please post the code inside of your question, instead of in a pastebin. This way, your question can be useful even for other users later on. I have cleaned up your post a bit this way, so it does fit the standards of SO better.

Comment: @jdweng I've done what you've said here. It became this one : http://i.hizliresim.com/AnygXr.png , one question: can it be about the save button ?

Comment: @jdweng it still doesn't work by the way.

Comment: You could do that insert in one statement. and why add all those params and not use them?

Comment: @Crowcoder it doesn't matter if i do it in one statement, or in more than one. I just wonder why that code doesn't work. There has to be a connection error, but couldn't find it.

Comment: If there is an error you can trap it as an Exception and read it.

Comment: Test your sql statements in SSMS.  The error message are much better and will indicate if the data is really in the database.  There is a "New Query" Button on SSMS where you can enter you sql.  Also if you right click on the database tables there are a number of useful queries you can run to help determine where the error is occuring.

Comment: @jdweng it's not an error actually. The program is starting without and error but when i enter the inputs and click the save button, nothing happens in the database.

Comment: The is no code in the add method ekle_Click(),  I don;t see a save button in the code posted()

Comment: You may not receive an exception in visual studio if it fails in SQL. I'm not sure what all the reasons for this are but sometimes SQL returns success even if not all the statements were processed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Cut that SQL statement out and drop it into SQL server management studio and see if it runs. You will see it throws a few errors mainly due to your variables.

A few things I found in briefly reviewing:

1. Don't use ntext change those declarations to varchar(50).
2. @room_no int = @room_no will fail. (did you mean @roomno = "' + RoomNo + "')
3. Your parameters addwithvalue don't match the parameters in your sql (were you aware of this?)